# How to make Remote Bombs work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, alchemist

This is a question about the [Remote Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/remote-bomb) feat available to Alchemists and any other class that can use their Bombs.

It basically allows to set explosive traps and would see great use for a saboteur style of character, but here is the problem : detonating the bomb from a distance is an Intelligence check with a massive DC, and it's almost impossible for a character that doesn't have game breaking amounts of Intelligence to use this reliably (even with 20 intelligence, you only have 25% chance to succeed if you are adjacent to the bomb, and this drops by 5% for every 10 feet you move away from it). Or maybe you can spend 2 minutes to take 20 on the check...

So, is there any way to make the actual remote component of this feat reliable and useful ?

Comment: Are you asking, "As a player, how can I make use of remote bombs without having to deal with these difficult intelligence checks," or are you asking, "As a DM, how can I make the remote bombs easier to use but not trivial, so that players/NPCs can do fun things with them?"

Comment: He seems to be asking "As a player, I want remote bomb to do something that it can't do RAW, so help me justify houseruling this to be better."

Comment: Huh. I was unaware that *Pathfinder* eliminated the *D&D 3.5* option to [take 10 and take 20](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Take-10) on ability checks. That's weird *and* sad.

Comment: Actually, they didn't : "Ability Checks and Caster Level Checks: The normal take 10 and take 20 rules apply for ability checks. Neither rule applies to concentration checks or caster level checks."  
http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/usingSkills.html

Answer (score 3):

### Inspiration

The [Investigator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator#TOC-Inspiration-Ex-) class (from the Advanced Class Guide) has an ability called Inspiration, which allows them to augment skill and ability checks:

> An investigator has the ability to augment skill checks and ability checks through his brilliant inspiration.  ... As a free action, he can expend one use of inspiration from his pool to add 1d6 to the result of that check ...

Don't want to multiclass? The [Inspiring Cognatogen](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/inspiring-cognatogen-su) discovery gives an alchemist access to inspiration die. (Thanks to Oblivious Sage for pointing this out).

Comment: Alchemists can also use the Inspiring Cognatogen discovery to gain access to an inspiration pool.

Comment: This is a tiny bonus at massive cost.

Comment: But it is an actual bonus, not arbitrarily changing the rules.

Comment: @GreySage Arbitrarily changing the rules seems to be exactly what the question is asking for.

Comment: @KRyan - The way the question is written, either current rules or a homebrew are reasonable answers. Perhaps OP will clarify what their preference is.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 methods of detonations for Remote Bomb: Time, Proximity, and Trigger.

Time: bomb explodes after a certain amount of time (up to 1 min/level).

Proximity: bomb explodes if anyone touches it.

Trigger: bomb explodes when you make an intelligence check (DC 20 + 1/10 feet between you and the bomb).

Time can be useful if you know where creatures will be. For example, if you are running away from something. Say it has a move speed of 30ft/round, and you are 60 feet away, you drop the bomb with a delay of 2 rounds. Effective in a small corridor, against unintelligent enemies (since smart ones will probably see you set the bomb). It can also be effective as an early attack, eg. you set the bomb in the middle of a group of enemies while invisible, then retreat and start throwing bombs like normal. Another useful way is to set up a distraction, set the bomb in a nearby room, then do something when everyone runs to check out the explosion. Another way is to ambush a non-hostile enemy, set the bomb near a non-hostile you want to kill, then time your attacks to coincide with it.

Proximity is your standard trap arrangement.  Use bait (a couple of gold coins, so it explodes when someone tries to pick them up), misdirection (tell them it is a useful potion), or just put it on the ground and hope someone steps on it (The discovery doesn't state whether moving in the same square as it automatically counts as touching it, so this could be more risky).

Trigger is the hardest to activate, but it also lets you affect the bomb after it is placed. Due to its uncertain nature, I wouldn't try to trigger it as someone walks by (unless you have lots of time and opportunities), since it more likely will not go off when you want it to. Rather, I would use it in a similar way to the distraction use of Time, but when you don't know when you will want it. Imagine you are meeting with a king or enemy warlord, place the bomb to the side of the room or where you can see it but they can't. Then, while talking (say, after you learn about whatever McGuffin you care about) you can trigger it. The big difference here is that usually, people won't randomly start attacking you while you are talking to them, so you can take multiple attempts at detonation without losing anything.

Ultimately, Remote Bomb and Delayed Bomb are utility tools, they don't give you a lot of power or damage, but they have a few niche uses that can be effective given the right circumstances. How effective they are really depends on how creative you are with them, and how often you create situations where they can shine.

Comment: Can't you also use a spell to activate the bomb?

Comment: @Momonga-sama in what way?

Comment: I'm not asking anything about how the feat works, it's about how making the actual "remote" stuff usable.

Comment: Mage hand. I know that it does not appear on Alchemist's spell list. However granted by an item or something similar couldn't it be used to activate the bomb in a different way or make it easier?

Answer (score -2):

#### Add a skill-based or level-based component

Ability checks are hard because you can only do so much to improve your abilities, and since abilities affect so much those improvements are (and should be) expensive. Anything that’s a pure ability check is effectively something you *cannot train to be better at*, since if you could there should be some skill in play, so that training (ranks) can be brought to bear.

That being the case, picking an appropriate skill to use for triggering remote mines, or even just letting the alchemist add his class level to the check, would be appropriate. Spellcraft, since these are magical bombs, might work, and still uses Intelligence. Use Magic Device might be even more appropriate, but its Charisma use makes it less ideal. You might even go so far as to call it an Int-based UMD check, perhaps.

If you do this, the skill check will still be difficult at low levels, but by mid levels (or even lowish levels with some investment), they’ll become trivial and reliable. This seems appropriate for activating your own class features to me. Of course, at any level, enough distance will eliminate any chance of success you have.

Comment: If you propose a houserule in an answer, you really should describe your relevant experience of using that houserule, as per our 'Back it Up' policy.